# Is possible to have recurring slots in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I've set reproduction repository:

https://github.com/devidwong/recurring-slot

I use Vue runtime-only, so I cannot attach fiddle with `Vue.extend` (requires template compiler)

Vue 3 is pretty new stuff. I used it for exploring purposes. I don't know if this would work on Vue 2, but I just wonder if this component should work anyways:

comment.template.html:

```html
<div class="comment">
    <slot :currentComment="comment"></slot>
    <Comment v-for="reply in comment.replies" :key="reply.id" :comment="reply">
        <slot :currentComment="reply"></slot>
    </Comment>
</div>
```

usage:

comments.template.html

```html
<Comment v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id" :comment="comment">
    <template #default="{ currentComment }">
        <div>by {{ currentComment.author }}</div>
    </template>
</Comment>
```

for structure:

```js
comments: [
      {
        id: 1,
        author: 'Goodman',
        replies: [
          {
            id: 11,
            author: 'RepeatingMan',
            replies: [
              {
                id: 111,
                author: 'ExpectedMan',
                replies: [
                  {
                    id: 1111,
                    author: 'MelodyOfFuture',
                    replies: []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I get `Repeatimg man` rendered 3 times instead of `ExpectedMan`, and `MelodyOfFuture`. In my opinion second slot gets same comment prop as first one.
I expect to have nested comments and to define inside stuff just once.

Is this possible?

Comment: do you want to show the authors one under the other?

Comment: yes. As you can see the structure is good, but data always comes from same level

Comment: See if [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-field-9epvi) helps

Comment: Nice, that you point me codesandbox, but if you post solution - your comment component is not recurring

Answer (score 3):

Don't expose the comment again to the parent component via slot, just print the author name and it's comment in the `Comment` Component :

```
<div class="comment">
   {{comment.author}}
    <Comment v-for="reply in comment.replies" :key="reply.id" :comment="reply">
        <slot :currentComment="reply"></slot>
    </Comment>
</div>
```

parent component :

```
<Comment v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id" :comment="comment">
</Comment>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-morse-63b0r?file=/src/Comment.vue)**

in the live demo i tried to simulate the stackoverflow comments style.

Comment: this is workaround. I want to define `<h4>{{ comment.author }}</h4>` (or any kind of wrapper) in parent component like in normal (non-recurring)  component. Can you precisely point where is the limitation? I don't create app - I explore and experiment. There is many ways to archieving this

Comment: you're welcome, what about [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-night-lxco3?file=/src/Comment.vue) i used named scoped slot in parent and child component

Comment: You hit the jackpot with defining details two times (in parent and child) for infinite rendering :). I found that one slot is not neccessary, also naming slot is not required. Also details can be passed as a Component in prop to child - so now it is defined only once. Sadly not in the place I wanted, but it's ok (I dont expect it to have more child). I updated repo from question. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome, ok, in the case of recurrence your should use render function instead of template like i did when i built my component using vue 3 https://github.com/boussadjra/vue3-router-tree

Answer (score 0):

repo is updated

https://github.com/devidwong/recurring-slot

parent:

```html
<Comment
      v-for="comment in comments"
      :key="comment.id"
      :comment="comment"
      :detailsComponent="CommentDetails"
    >
      <template #default="{ currentComment }">
        <CommentDetails
            :currentComment="currentComment"
        />
      </template>
    </Comment>
```

child:

```html
<div class="comment">
    <slot :currentComment="comment"></slot>
    <Comment
        v-for="reply in comment.replies"
        :key="reply.id"
        :comment="reply"
        :detailsComponent="detailsComponent"
    >
      <template #default="{ currentComment }">
        <component
            :is="detailsComponent"
            :currentComment="currentComment"
            :detailsComponent="detailsComponent"
        />
      </template>
    </Comment>
  </div>
```

details:

```html
<div>
    by {{ currentComment.author }}
</div>
```

don't forget to declare CommentDetails (in parent) as component, and as data entry:

```js
{
components: {
    Comment,
    CommentDetails
},
data: () => ({
    CommentDetails,
    comments: [...]
})
}
```